# jtable header hiding/without column

Tags: java, swing, header, jtable

I want to create a table, for example, that has 3 column headers but only shows two columns and hiding the 3rd.

The last column is fixed and used to hide/show columns like most of applications do by clicking it and showing a popup menu.

Cheers

probably I didn't describe clearly. I know removeColumn/addColumn. By clicking on the table header, i can add column or remove them. However what I am curious is that a dedicated column header at the most right corner of the table header, which is fixed, small width and with descriptive table-like icon. So, by left mouse clicking this column header, a popup menu shows up for hiding/showing columns.This column header doesn't actually have column or rows but the header, like JDownloader does.

Answer (score 4):

you have look at, [JTable methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html),

- [JTable#removeColumn(TableColumn aColumn)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29)
- [JTable#addColumn(TableColumn aColumn)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#addColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29)

these two methods only to hide/show `JTables Column(s)`, data are still available in the `TableModel`

Comment: probably I didn't describe clearly. I know removeColumn/addColumn. By clicking on the table header, i can add column or remove them. However what I am curious is that a dedicated column header at the most right corner of the table header, which is fixed, small width and with descriptive table-like icon. So, by left mouse clicking this column header, a popup menu shows up for hiding/showing columns. This column header doesn't actually have column or rows but the header, like JDownloader does.

Comment: then answer by @Robin (re-invent the wheel +1) is right way to go,

Answer (score 3):

The `JXTable` of `SwingX` has built-in UI for showing/hiding columns in a pop-up (unfortunately I could not find an image of it).

You can of course create this yourself using the suggested methods but why re-invent the wheel

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that you can accomplish this:

Correct Approach :

Remove the column from table

```
TableColumn lastColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(lastIndex);
table.removeColumn(lastColumn);
```

Don't do this :

Set the width of last column as 0:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(lastIndex).setPrefferedWidth(0);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(lastIndex).setMaximumWidth(0);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(lastIndex).setMinimumWidth(0);
```

Comment: Approach 1 is a not a solution.  Not a good idea to do that.  removeColumn/addColumn is what you should look at.